# C# Architecture/Pattern for Tenant-Specific Business Logic

Tags: c#, design-patterns, c#-6.0

Say you have a multi-tenant app.  A `Tenant` has various properties:

```
public class Tenant{
  public string TenantName {get; set;}
  public string TenantUrl {get; set;}
}
```

This way when my service layer sends emails, for example, I can do the following:

```
 SendEmail(Tenant.FromEmailAddress, recipientEmailAddress)
```

This works well for *properties*.  In many places throughout my business logic, I'm encountering cases where tenant-specific *behaviors* must be accounted for.  One example is retrieving photos for the homepage:

```
public List<string> GetPhotoUrls(){
     if(currentTenant == TenantA){
         // logic to go off to retrieve from one third party
     } else if (currentTenant == TenantB){
         // totally different logic
     } else...  // one for each tenant

     // do some stuff
     // return stuff
}
```

`GetPhotoUrls` is a simple example - but there are cases like this in many places in my business logic.  I'm looking for a **simple pattern where I can define and implement tenant-specific logic**.  The overall goal is to get all tenant-specific logic in one place so tenant creation and definition is easy.

I would like the developer experience to read along the lines of:

```
public List<string> GetPhotoUrls(){
     currentTenant.GetPhotoUrls(); // define this logic on the tenant object somehow
     // do some stuff
     // return stuff
}
```

What patterns/constructs are available to achieve this?

Comment: What seems very odd is that you retrieve data based on the tenant where tenants are hardcoded...

Comment: I don't think your photourl logic is tenant specific, rather than photo source specific, so each tenant should have a photoprovider which you assign depending on what type of a tenant it is?

Comment: @JanneMatikainen - this is a poor example - the logic is indeed different.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - that's what I'm trying to avoid - hardcoding every tenant to determine behavior.  I want to consolidate behavior on the Tenant so I can just say `Tenant.DoThis`

Answer (score 1):

Use the strategy pattern in your case. The pattern is best applied when you see `switch` statements or multiple `if` statements to simplify the client so that it delegates custom implementation to dependent interfaces. You may also use in combination of factory pattern. To illustrate this:

```
public interface ITenant{
   List<string> GetPhotoUrls();
}

public class TenantA:ITenant{
   public string TenantName {get; set;}
   public string TenantUrl {get; set;}
   public List<string> GetPhotoUrls(){
         //A implementation
   }
}

public class TenantB:ITenant{
   public string TenantName {get; set;}
   public string TenantUrl {get; set;}  
   public List<string> GetPhotoUrls(){
         //B implementation
   }
}

public class SomeTenantApp{
   public SomeTenantApp(ITenant tenant){
      _tenant = tenant;
   }

   public void DoSomething(){
     var urls  = _tenant.GetPhotoUrls();
     //do something
   }
}

public static class TenantFactory{
    public static ITenant Create(string id)
    {
        //logic to get concrete tenant
        return concreteTenant;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tenant = TenantFactory.Create("A");
        var app = var SomeTenantApp(tenant);
        app.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

The client (SomeTenantApp) won't have to change. You delegated the implementation to the concrete class which owns the logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build SaaS, I'd strongly recommend using ASP.NET Core and dependency injection to overcome multi-tenancy issue.

*You can defined your tenant class :*

```
public class AppTenant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Hostnames { get; set; }
}
```

*Next you can resolve a tenant from the current request*

```
public class AppTenantResolver : ITenantResolver<AppTenant>
{
    IEnumerable<AppTenant> tenants = new List<AppTenant>(new[]
    {
        new AppTenant {
            Name = "Tenant 1",
            Hostnames = new[] { "localhost:6000", "localhost:6001" }
        },
        new AppTenant {
            Name = "Tenant 2",
            Hostnames = new[] { "localhost:6002" }
        }
    });

    public async Task<TenantContext<AppTenant>> ResolveAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        TenantContext<AppTenant> tenantContext = null;
        // it's just a sample...
        var tenant = tenants.FirstOrDefault(t =>
            t.Hostnames.Any(h => h.Equals(context.Request.Host.Value.ToLower())));

        if (tenant != null)
        {
            tenantContext = new TenantContext<AppTenant>(tenant);
        }

        return tenantContext;
    }
}
```

*Wiring it up :*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMultitenancy<AppTenant, AppTenantResolver>();
}
```

*Getting the current tenant (whenever you need it) :*

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private AppTenant tenant;

    public HomeController(AppTenant tenant)
    {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

For more info take a look at [**SaasKit**](https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit)
[**Building multi-tenant applications with ASP.NET Core (ASP.NET 5)**](http://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-5-multitenancy)